# Shopify render liquid template performance issue

Tags: reactjs, performance, shopify-app, shopify-liquid

I am working on app **Filter and Search** on Shopify. **Filter and Search** is a React project

There was an issue, this app has a lot of settings and customize that make bundle size large and render take too much time. performance score of my app is not good

I am wondering that is there anyway

> after settings and customize has any updated. I will build my project to **static html** and when shopify render my liquid template I just need embedded that **static html**

please correct me if I am wrong

thank everyone